# How can I easily get the Ethereum 2.0 network's fork digest and fork version?

Tags: eth-2.0, p2p, libp2p

Ethereum 2.0 nodes communicate through a libp2p network. Two indicators of talking to "correct" nodes on the same network are the "fork digest" and the "fork version" parameters.

How can I easily get the Ethereum 2.0 network's fork digest and fork version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the fork version and the fork digest are part of the `eth2` field included in every node's ENR.

To extract it, you can use the [ENR Viewer](https://enr-viewer.com/) or any other ENR decoding tool. This screenshot shows the ENR for a node on the [Spadina](https://github.com/goerli/medalla/tree/master/spadina) test network:

[image: screenshot of the enr viewer]

The `eth2` field contains the following: `0x09fb0a1200000002ffffffffffffffff`

- The first four bytes are the fork digest `09 fb 0a 12`
- The next four bytes are the fork version `00 00 00 02`
- The next four bytes are the "next" fork version `ff ff ff ff` (upcoming forks, here: none)
- The next four bytes is the "next" fork epoch `ff ff ff ff` (upcoming forks, here: none)